# Kotlin naming convention for properties

Tags: kotlin, naming-conventions

> Names of properties holding references to singleton objects can use
> the same naming style as object declarations:
>
> `val PersonComparator: Comparator<Person> = ...`

I don't understand what this means. A singleton object means there is only a single instance of the object but singletons are scoped. If I have a single instance of an object within my class, am I allowed to use this naming convention or is it strictly for singletons declared using the `object : SomeType` declaration?

Comment: There is a difference between "true singletons" and scoped stuff like DI injected singletons. True singletons can only have 1 instance in the entire proram. In Java this is easily done with an enum, e.g. enum Foo { INSTANCE; /*stuff*/ }, and in Kotlin it's done with object. Conversely there is nothing actually stopping you from creating more than one @Singleton class in Spring. You can just instantiate the object manually

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it appears to be referencing a singleton created with the `object` declaration. [Elsewhere](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html) on the Kotlin website, singleton is used to refer to `object` declarations:

> Singleton may be useful in several cases, and Kotlin (after Scala) makes it easy to declare singletons:

```
object DataProviderManager {
    fun registerDataProvider(provider: DataProvider) {
        // ...
    }
    val allDataProviders: Collection<DataProvider>
        get() = // ...
}
```